# Resources for planning and schedule a launch-watching day-trip in Florida?

Tags: launch, reference-request, tourism, outreach

I know some busy people in Florida who I'd like to encourage to take a break and go watch a launch.

They aren't "space people" and won't be keeping up on technical blogs or NASA or industry websites.

Are there good on-line resources written for the general public that address

1. checking out launch schedules
2. picking a good launch
3. where to go, and to park
4. where to eat
5. typical delays and traffic

for a first-time visitor by car to Cape Canaveral wanting to watch a launch?

Comment: Are you asking about actually going on base or just watching from any public space? Those are different orders of magnitude in effort.

Comment: @cms I hadn't thought that far without any information or experience, luckily [your answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36739/12102) nicely covers both, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options for viewing a launch from Cape Canaveral: Pay to enter Kennedy Space Center (KSC), or watch the launch for free from a public space. The above choice will dictate what information you need to be aware of.

#### 1) From KSC:

KSC long ago monetized launch viewing. Here is the link to their page with a thorough description of everything you need to know in order to view the launch:

[How to watch a rocket launch from Kennedy Space Center](https://www.kennedyspacecenter.com/blog/03/how-to-watch-a-rocket-launch)

Pros of going to KSC:

- Closest possible viewing for the general public
- Get to see all the other cool stuff at KSC (the museum is top notch)

Cons include:

- Costs money.
- Very crowded during summer season (and especially launch days)
- All day event
- Launch could get scrubbed

#### 2) From a public space outside of KSC:

You can see the vehicle climb, see the exhaust and hear the boom from just about anywhere in north Brevard county. The list of public places you can go that you can see the pad is much smaller. Here is an excellent list of places to go (not all of them can see pad 39A however):

[List of convenient public viewing places outside of KSC](https://www.spacecoastlaunches.com/viewing-spots/)

The only two places I know you can see (with binoculars) the vehicle on the ground is:

- [on FL 401 near Port Canaveral](https://goo.gl/maps/W2BRNLQJLu2S2Xf27)
- From a boat on the banana river (my preference ;p)

Pros of watching from a public space:

- Quick; can just 'show up'.
- Cheap
- Only option for night launches.
- Lots of options, many near restaurants and other conveniences.

Cons for public spaces:

- Only a few places the liftoff isn't obscured by trees or buildings.
- need binoculars to really enjoy it.

Comment: This sums it up very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The following video was quite well-received:

Though I guess it's not “written“, as asked, but that might be more of an advantage in terms of motivation.

This addresses points 3-5. As for points 1-2, I can recommend the app “Space Launch Now“, which is always up to date and provides good supplementary information.

I hope your friends aren't discouraged by scrubs too badly. It's definitely worth the effort to keep showing up!

Comment: I've asked for "...good on-line resources **written** for the general public..." and so a link to a 16 minute video unfortunately does not qualify by itself. It's really hard to skim a video, while **skimming something written** is easy, and can be aided by a search function in the browser. Is there a transcript of this video available somewhere? If not, could you transcribe a few key points to text in your answer here? Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh I might do that after the FH launch or if it gets scrubbed. Pretty busy at the moment. Sorry I can't help immediately.

Comment: still looking forward to an answer. If you have a text copy of the closed captions, even that would be good. "Watch this video" is really a comment, not a proper Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: `-1` for proposing to "go watch my monetized YouTube channel" as a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: You did a nice job of adding a short summary [in this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36080/12102) with the "in essence..." paragraph. Can you do something similar here? I think it's really great to link to helpful resources and I am confident that this is such a resource, but a Stack Exchange answer needs to at least summarize what's in the resource in order to avoid being a "link-only" answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, feel really bad for this. Downvote deserved. Will comply as soon as I have some quiet free time without any other urgent thought on my mind.

Comment: It just needs a few links to on-line resources added in the beginning, but keep the existing answer. The video is an excellent summary of all the issues!

Comment: fyi I've just asked [From where do apps that listen to “Kennedy Space Center Communications” get their audio feed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36114/12102)