# From where do apps that listen to “Kennedy Space Center Communications” get their audio feed?

Tags: launch, nasa, kennedy-space-center, audio

Watching the Everyday Astronaut video [The best places to watch a rocket launch in Florida!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBLeg0CvHek) near the end there are mentions of some "viewer tweets" including one that caught my eye.

> Download a scanner app and listen to “Kennedy Space Center Communications” - at least for Shuttle launches they would broadcast some of the launch prep.

This suggests to me that there are audio feeds available to the public, and the app taps into them via a wireless connection. But perhaps not, I don't really know what a "scanner app" is.

Are such feeds publicly available?

Were such apps really around when the Shuttle was launching?

[image]

Comment: During the Shuttle launches that I saw from the causeway, ham-radio type guys were listening to (and playing for the crowd) mission audio rebroadcasts on complicated looking radios.  Anything about radio other than where the power switch is on my car dash is over my head though.  Iphone app store opened in 2008 so it's barely possible there could have been such apps but I never saw it.  Some info on monitoring here: http://www.monitoringtimes.com/html/Monitoring%20NASA%20and%20Space%20Communications.pdf